# Does anyone know why I am getting the following error?: Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)

Tags: java, android, xml

Hi can anyone help me with this problem. I am using Eclipse for Android and have just created a number of buttons and have labelled them correctlt(made sure I did) and set them an id which I have also included in my strings file. However when I go to set up the butotn with an OnClickListener and create the onClick method I get the error outlined above. There is red error lines on the dot (period) between button1 and setOnClickListener. I dont know what is going on here. Ive also included the xml and strings classes. 
N.B. there is more code for the Main.java activity but i dont think it is necessary for this question.

Thanks for the help!

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener) {

    }
```

Comment: Those `XML`s are totally irrelevant to the question. Please remove them.

Comment: `new View.OnClickListener` what is this sintax?

Comment: `.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {...});`

Comment: thanks I have resolved it now I realise my syntax is wrong. I think I am maybe a bit tired for programming at this time of night! :)

Answer (score 2):

The method in your Java sample ends at the brace  right after the "return" statement; the next two lines are outside of any method, and the one with the errors, being a statement, is illegal outside of a method.

Answer (score 1):

Put those bottom two statements inside your function and then edit the setOnClidkListener Like so:

```
button1.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {

});
```